# Bash script to copy specific directories with pattern matching

Tags: bash, grep, find, regular-expression

How can I copy directories from one location to another location that matches a pattern.

**For example:**

```
source = /media/src/
destination = /media/dest/
```

- The pattern is as `/b/w{2}_/w{2}/b`. i.e all directories like `aa_bb`, `fg_sd`, `re_ya`, `AA_BB`, `aa_Bx`, `Ba_BB` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
cp /media/src/[[:lower:]][[:lower:]]_[[:lower:]][[:lower:]] /media/dest/
```

The `[[:lower:]]` is a POSIX defined [character class](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01) which matches all characters classified as lowercase letters.

**Edit**: To match all characters use the character class `alpha` instead of `lower`:

```
cp /media/src/[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]_[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]] /media/dest/
```

Comment: Sorry but it will just copy the directory with lower case, how about the directory name like `aa_bb, fg_sd , re_ya, AA_BB , aa_Bx , Ba_BB`

Comment: @Nepal12 use `alpha`. see my edit

Comment: Thanks it worked, btw can we do this using regular expression (just curious).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is what you wanted. It searches for directories with format xx_yy/ab_cd/&&_$$ (2char_2char) and copies the content to a new directory .

```
usage : ./script.sh

cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash

MYDIR="/media/src/"
NEWDIRPATH="/media/dest"
DIRS=`ls -l $MYDIR | grep "^d" | awk '{print $9}'`
for DIR in $DIRS
do
       total_characters=`echo $DIR | wc -m`
       if [ $total_characters -eq 6 ]; then
                has_underscore=`echo "$DIR" | grep "_"`
                if [ "$has_underscore" != "" ]; then
                        echo "${DIR}"
                        start_string_count=`echo $DIR | awk -F '_' '{print $1}' | wc -m`
                        end_string_count=`echo $DIR | awk -F '_' '{print $2}' | wc -m`
                        echo "start_string_count => $start_string_count ; end_string_count => $end_string_count"
                        if [ $start_string_count -eq 3 ] && [ $end_string_count -eq 3 ]; then

                                cp -r $DIR $NEWDIRPATH/
                        fi
                fi
        fi
done
```